# java ee lookup ejbs from from different app

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, ejb

Java EE Tutorial is not helpful at all. Internet search was underwhelming.

I have an EJB module that is deployed to glassfish by itself. It has @Local and @Remote annotated iterfaces which are both implemented by the concrete class.

Then i have a REST resource that needs to get a reference to that ejb module and invoke some methods.

Can you give me a barebones, simple example of how that is done? I mean, i can't even inject SessionContext into my rest app, as it crashes... Please, keep it simple.

The ejb should just have a:

```
public String getMsg(){ 
    return "ohai";
}
```

The rest service:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String asd(){
    return <the myterious ejb that was injected somehow>.getMsg();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention - using NetBeans 8.0.2, Glassfish 4.1

Comment: And a followup: Can you give me a _good_, _decent_ book that explains these things? As i said, official Java EE Tutorial is written for aliens. "It's easy" - they say, "CDI and Resource look up makes your life easier by managing lifecycle and intantiation for other objects for you" - they say. But so far i find it infinitely easier to build a goddamn native JMS client in C than in the easy, trivial java ee.

Comment: I have O'Reilly Enterprise JavaBeans, I found this book to really helpful.

Comment: Is your rest service cdi managed? Depends on whether you are using default beans.xml as cdi archive identifier, or annotation as cdi trigger, you will have to let the rest ckass be cdi managed

Comment: Rest class is annotated. I'm sorry, you're talking about deployment descriptors, right?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, i figured it out. Using NetBeans, but probably applicable to Eclipse. Server - glassfish

Create webapp, an EJB -> call EJB from webapp. All these run inside the same server as separate modules.

First: create an EJB module, it will be deployed on its own:

**remote interface:**

```
package main;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface YourRemoteInterface{
     public String tellMeSomething();
     public void otherMethod(); //etc...
}
```

then create the EJB implementation class:

**concrete implementation**

```
package main;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.EJB; //crucial to JNDI lookup

@Remote(RemoteInterface.class)
@Stateless
@EJB(name="java:global:/MYSTUFF", beanInterface=YourRemoteInterface.class)
public class YourConcreteClass implements YourRemoteInterface{

     @Override
     public String tellMeSomething(){//...} //and do the other methods
}
```

@EJB name attribute names your bean, that you will use to look it up. Can by any name. For ex: "some-name", or "java:global/YourConcreteClass"

Part two - webapp:
For web app i used a rest service, but surely can be another EJB or a SE client app. For SE client you'd need to set connection info, but that for another life.

```
@Path("/somePath")
public class Service{

     @GET
     @Produces("text/plain")
     public String qwe(){
         try{
           javax.naming.InitialCOntext ic = new javax.naming.InitialContext();

           YourRemoteInterface rb = (YourRemoteInterface)ic.lookup("java:global:/MYSTUFF");
           return rb.tellMeSomething();

         } catch (Exception ex) {
              return "F*uck your life";
         }
     }
}
```

Now, from **Project Properties** of your webapp, you need to:

1) add the ejb jar file to **Libraries** so it shows in the Compile tab. I used the "Add project" button

2) Build -> Packaging: add the ejb jar file to WAR content. I used "Add file/folder", where i navigated to NetBeans projects / the EJB module / build / dist

**note:** you may experience an error when trying to deploy the ejb, or redeploy it. Error name is: **java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name main.RemoteInterface#main.RemoteInterface for EJB RemoteBean** . Skipping the vague explanation, to cure it, you need to execute a command in glassfish:

**asadmin set server.ejb-container.property.disable-nonportable-jndi-names="true"**

Now, you can compile the webapp and deploy it. Should work.

At the end it's that simple. I swear i've eaten the WHOLE ejb section in glassfish tutorial and nowhere do they tell you this stuff. It's so annoying.